# The HTML button with JS code does not perform the action I requested

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was testing changing the JS commands, but the button doesn’t do anything. I’m thinking, it’s the CSS or HTML that’s wrong. I tried it without any CSS, a much more basic code, and it works for the JS part, and it deletes the div. It might be something of the CSS, but I’m not sure.

This is my code:

```js
function eliminarDiv() {
  var div = document.querySelector("al-login");
  
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/insaniburger');
.al-login {
  width: 300px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(95, 184, 220);
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
  line-height: 0px;
}

.button-x {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 267px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(135, 135, 135);
  border: 2px rgb(135, 135, 135);
}

.button-x .x-button {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Insaniburger';
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
<div class="al-login">
  <!--fas fa-eye fa-square-x-->
  <button class="button-x" onclick="eliminarDiv()"><p class="x-button">X</p></button>
  <p style="line-height: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">Dear user, you can login</p>
  <br style="line-height: 0px;">
</div>
```

Comment: _`document.querySelector("al-login")`_ — I don’t see an `<al-login>` element anywhere in your HTML. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. Read the documentation: [CSS selectors](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors).

Comment: `document.querySelector("al-login")` should be `document.querySelector(".al-login")`. You forgot the leading ".". Also, if you [open your browser's console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) you will see those helpful error messages.

Comment: Also, [validate your HTML](//validator.nu). You cannot have a `<p>` element inside a `<button>`.

Comment: Yeah, use `span` inside button not `p` if you want to modify it using class.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```js
function eliminarDiv() {
  var div = document.querySelector(".al-login");//you forgot to add a point
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/insaniburger');
.al-login {
  width: 300px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(95, 184, 220);
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
  line-height: 0px;
}

.button-x {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 267px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgb(135, 135, 135);
  border: 2px rgb(135, 135, 135);
  cursor:pointer;  /* This can hit the user to close it */
}

.button-x .x-button {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Insaniburger';
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
<div class="al-login">
  <button class="button-x" onclick="eliminarDiv()"><span class="x-button">X</span></button>
  <!--although it works in some case, do not use p inside button, also, you can just write what you want in a button-->
  <p style="line-height: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">Dear user, you can login</p>
  <br style="line-height: 0px;">
</div>
```

Please remember that you should add a point before the class.
Also, use span instead of p in a button, though it works in some case.
The last thing I change is that I add *cursor:pointer;* to your code, so users can know that this could be closed(because some user think default cursor is not available to click, such as me)